# Prove that $\overline{(a,b)}\subseteq [a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

In my note, right after the author has defined what [adherent points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adherent_point) are,
$$ x\in \mathbb{R} \textrm{ is called an adherent point of $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ if } (x-\rho,x+\rho)\cap A\neq \emptyset
\textrm{ for all $\rho>0$},$$
and then denote by $\overline{A}$ the set of all adherent points of $A$. Then, it gives an example without explanation that $\overline{(a,b)}=[a,b]$. I tried to confirm it on my own. I could only manage to prove that $[a,b]\subseteq \overline{(a,b)}$. How to show the converse inclusion?

I think I would proceed it by contrapositive. Assuming $x\notin [a,b]$, I want to find an $\rho>0$ such that $(x-\rho,x+\rho)\cap (a,b)=\emptyset$. I drew a line to understand the situation. To me, it appears that whenever $x<a$, one can pick $\rho = (a-x)/2$, and when $x>b$, one can pick $\rho=(x-b)/2$. So, altogether if $x\notin [a,b]$, one should pick $\rho = \min \{(a-x)/2,(x-b)/2\}$. Is that all?

Note: The author has not introduced any kind of results before the example. Therefore, I avoid the result that says that $A$ is open iff $A^c$ is closed, or that unions of two open sets is open, or any other result. Many similar results will be introduced much later. I just want to see if the converse inclusion can be proved by using the definition of adherent point only.

Comment: $\overline X = \operatorname{int}(X) \cup \partial X$.

Comment: @Zest I know this result, but I will refrain from using it as it is not introduced yet. Is my proof wrong?

Comment: The limit points of the open interval $(a, b)$ consist of all the points in $(a, b)$ as well as the end points $x = a$ and $x = b$. By definition, the closure of a set $A$ is the union of $A$ and all its limit points. Hence, the closure of $(a, b)$ is the closed interval $[a, b]$.

Comment: @Dr.Sundar By limit points, you mean cluster points? Could you please stick to the definition of adherent points, as this is the definition I use in my note? I provided a proof; does it look OK, or is it wrong?

Comment: Your proof seems fine. You've shown that for all $x \notin [a,b]$, there exists $\rho$ such that $(x-\rho, x+\rho) \cap (a,b) = \emptyset$. Therefore $x \notin \overline{(a,b)}$. By contrapositive, $x\in\overline{(a,b)} \rightarrow x\in[a,b]$, so $\overline{(a,b)}\subseteq [a,b]$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is fine, except one problem when you collect the two cases into $\rho=\min\left\{\frac{a-x}{2},\frac{x-b}{2}\right\}$. One of these values will always be negative, so that won’t work. A fix would be $$\rho=\min\left\{\frac{|a-x|}{2},\frac{|b-x|}{2}\right\}.$$
(Actually, even $\rho=\min\left\{|a-x|,|b-x|\right\}$ works).

Oh, or you can say $\rho=\max\left\{\frac{a-x}{2},\frac{x-b}{2}\right\}$.